# where to use firebase onDisconnect in react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a test application with react native and firebase, I want to implement a presence status by updating a field in the users document when the app is closed. However, I do not know where to apply the disconnect, but I assumed it would be in the App.js in the componentWillUnmount. I am roughly new to both react native and firebase, kindly direct me if i am wrong. below is the way I have implemented it in my App.js but its not working. Also, I have shown the code only relevant to this problem.

App.js

```
      import { Firebase } from './Fire';


      export default class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            offline: 'offline',
          };
        }

        componentWillMount() {
          Firebase.init();
        }

        async componentWillUnmount() {
          const userUid = await Firebase.auth.currentUser.uid;

          const docRef = Firebase.firestore.collection('users').doc(userUid);
          const disconnectRef = docRef.onDisconnect().update({
            presenceStatus: this.state.offline
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the two Firebase databases here:

- The Realtime Database is the original Firebase database. It has support for detecting when a client disconnects on the server, and performing an operation, through its `onDisconnect` handler.
- Cloud Firestore is the newer database in Firebase. It has a quite different scalability model, and uses a connectionless protocol for communication between the clients and the servers. For that reason it does **not** support an `onDisconnect` handler.

So if you want to use `onDisconnect` you'll need to use the Firebase Realtime Database. You can either use that in addition to Cloud Firestore, or as an alternative to it.

Comment: Many thanks, found the documentation for implementing presence system on firebase

Comment: Quick question please. I am working on an on demand app that uses live tracking which would require the constant update of people’s lat and lng, and I plan to you Firebase Firestore for it. Having read a few scary articles (lol scary in terms of costing) about how Cost shoot up overnight. I’d like to know if it’s advisable to use firestore for this, as I think the entire BaaS it offers covers everything I need. If you can recommend the best approach possible to this, thanks.

Comment: Frequent small updates might be more cost efficient on the Realtime Database. But the calculator on the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) is probably your best go-to to find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AppState` to check the state of the app it can be any of this three:

> active - The app is running in the foreground.
>
> background - The app is running in the background. The user is either: in another app on the home screen [Android] on another Activity (even if it was launched by your app).
>
> [iOS] inactive - This is a state that occurs when transitioning between foreground & background and during periods of inactivity such as entering the Multitasking view or in the event of an incoming call.

Here's an example:

```
import { AppState } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState,
    offline: 'offline'
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = async (nextAppState) => {
    if (nextAppState.match(/inactive|background/) && this.state.appState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!');

      const userUid = await Firebase.auth.currentUser.uid;

      const docRef = Firebase.firestore.collection('users').doc(userUid);

      const disconnectRef = docRef.onDisconnect().update({
        presenceStatus: this.state.offline
      });
    }

    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }
}
```

For more detail for `AppState` go [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate#app-states)

Comment: thanks, but this does not detect when the app is closed, it only detects when its in the background. and I am also asking how to implement that with firebase firestore onDisconnect.
thanks